# Delphi TExpander Equivalent for VCL

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, vcl, expander

Using Delphi Tokyo with Windows10.

I would like to use Expanders in my VCL App, ie, to quickly show/hide info and to declutter UI's.  They are pretty common now and done very well elsewhere, eg, in [Microsoft's Fluent UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit/controls/expander) and also in Android, in fact they are part of [Android's Material Design](https://material.io/guidelines/components/expansion-panels.html#).

Delphi does include the [TExpander](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/FMX.StdCtrls.TExpander) Component for FMX, but for some reason does not have one for VCL (yet).

How are others handling this in their VCL Apps?

Is there a way to access and instantiate the Expander component that Windows itself uses with an API call?

Are folks just writing their own?  If so, I would welcome a link to a Github repo or equivalent so I don't have to reinvent the wheel. I am not asking anyone to write anything just asking if anyone's done this and for a pointer.  If not, I will write one myself and share.

I know there is the TCategoryGroupPanel, it just isn't very snappy and is somewhat awkward.  I also know that TMS sells something like this but unfortunately this will not work.

Alternate suggestions for getting an Expander Component into a Delphi VCL App would be most welcome too.

Thank you

Comment: Recommendation questions are off topic.

Comment: It's very doubtful they will *ever* add new controls to VCL. Since FMX is maturing, they're trying to slowly phase out VCL and encourage new projects to be built on FMX instead. Not that they will ever get rid of VCL, but they certainly aren't focusing on it. There are literally millions of custom third-party components/controls scattered across the internet. Unfortunately, finding them and linking them here for you is, as mentioned, off-topic.

Comment: We used `TCategoryPanelGroup` and by myself I cannot say it's awkward. In which way is awkward by your review? What features are you missing? Besides I would say this about the FMX control (its design time is, erm, not well designed).

Comment: @Jerry Many new VCL controls added in Seattle and then again in latest Tokyo update........

Comment: @Jerry: And indicated as being in the plans for the next version of Delphi (Carnival) according to the roadmap. So it appears that *very doubtful* is not quite true.

Comment: Apologies, I was basing my opinion off of years old information.

Comment: "*Is there a way to access and instantiate the Expander component that Windows itself uses with an API call?*" - there is no Expander control in the Win32 API.

Answer (score 5):

There is no native Windows control for collapsible panels (for use in VCL application), but you can use the mentioned [**TCategoryPanelGroup**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ExtCtrls.TCategoryPanelGroup). In my opinion I cannot say there are issues that could prevent you using that control.